# django ORM return top 10 match in manytomany relationship

Tags: django, manytomanyfield, sql-limit

My models.py has a manytomany relationship between `User` and `Tag`

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=32)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
```

How can I get top 10 tags ordered by the number of users with the tag? Something like

```
Tag.objects.order_by('user_set__count')[10]
```

This command doesn't work and django complains that

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'myuser_set' into field. Choices are: id, myuser, name

This is puzzling because `t1.user_set.count()` works where `t1` is a `Tag` instance.

Also, is there a better way to get the top 10 without order all data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below query return list of tags ordered by user count :

```
tags = Tag.objects.all().annotate(num_user = Count('user')).order_by('-num_user')
```

if you want 10 top, use this query:

```
tags = Tag.objects.all().annotate(num_user = Count('user')).order_by('-num_user')[:10]
```